# How can I make a variable salt to be used in the crypt function in C?

Tags: c, salt, cs50, crypt

As an assignment, I have to find a password of a user starting from the hash of that password (which was made using crypt). So, I'm trying to create a variable salt (2-letter string) which I then tend to use in the crypt function until the result matches the hash. However, when I try to make this variable salt, instead of two characters, I get 5/6 (even if I define the salt as an array of size 2). Does anyone know how this can be fixed? Difficult explanation, I know, but see code (and result) below.

```
char salt[2];
for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++)
{
    salt[0] = i;
    for (int j = 65; j < 91; j++)
    {
        salt[1] = j;
        printf("%s\n", salt);
    }
}
```

Outcome:
AA �g 
AB �g 
AC �g
AD �g 
AE �g
AF �g
...
...
...
ZW �g
ZX �g
ZY �g
ZZ �g

Where do these extra characters (=  �g) come from?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to print `salt` as a string but you don't actually have a string.  You have an array of two characters.  A string is terminated by a null byte.  By passing this array to `printf`, it attempts to read past the end of the array looking for a byte with value 0.  Reading past the end of an array invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case manifests as printing extra characters.

You need to add space in the array for the null terminator:

```
char salt[3];
salt[2] = 0;
```